# How to write a c++ concept for Heuristic function

Tags: c++, c++20, heuristics, concept

I am implementing a search algorithm with heuristic function in c++ 20.
I'm trying to constrain the function my algorithm can use with a concept like so:

```
template<typename SelfType, unsigned from, unsigned to>
concept Heuristic = requires(SelfType h, unsigned current)
{
    { h(current) } -> unsigned;

    assert(h(to) == 0);
};
```

Then I can write something like:

```
template<unsigned from, unsigned to>
struct H
{
    unsigned operator()(unsigned current)
    {
        return to - current + 100;
    }
};
```

Of course the assert does not work and that is not a valid heuristic because here h(to) is 100. I want to make the compiler check in compile time that h(to) equals 0.

Comment: You cannot have assertions in requirements. Concepts aside, how do you expect the compiler to verify that `h(to) == 100` if `h(to)` cannot be evaluated at compile-time? (It is not a constant expression in your example because `operator()` is not `constexpr`.)

Comment: Which compiler are you using? Even if you remove the `assert`, this (`-> unsigned;`) isn't valid. The correct way to write this is with `-> std::same_as<unsigned>;` or `-> std::convertible_to<unsigned>;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to make the compiler check in compile time that h(to) equals 0.

That would only be possible if the compiler was able to call `h(to)` at compile time. Which it can't, because there's no guarantee that whatever function gets invoked is `constexpr`. `SelfType` could be a function pointer type, and function pointers don't carry around `constexpr`. And concepts can't even check whether something is a constant expression or not.

When you start getting into questions of whether values map into the proper domain, or whether a function maps values into a domain, that isn't really a "concept" anymore. Or at least, it isn't a concept in the sense of the language feature.

That is, there are certain things when we consider to be requirements of a particular user of a concept which the language cannot verify. The C++20 concept library is full of these axiomatic concept requirements.

This is also a good reason why you should use a named member function for your heuristics, rather than assuming that anything which has an `operator()` overload that just so happens to map from unsigned integers to unsigned integers is a "heuristic".